# Is it possible to entirely disable authentication when using MinIO?

Tags: minio

Is it possible to entirely disable authentication for MinIO for local and CI usage? A bit of background: We're migrating from LocalStack to MinIO and large swathes of code rely on unauthenticated access to S3 so disabling auth entirely would be the simplest.

Comment: Hi. Im interested in this too. You solve it? 

Thanks

Comment: We haven't had any luck with this. 

Comment: Here some explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616518/minio-hows-bucket-policy-related-to-anonymous-authorized-access and here https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-anonymous-set.html. Basically you need to set anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

I finally use minio policies for unauthenticated access. Read this:

https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/reference/minio-cli/minio-mc/mc-policy.html

For example, I use download policy for unauthenticated access allowing users only download files.

Maybe this can help you

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Here's the good one - https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-anonymous-set.html